# Output of log.memory.slice in Geth debug_traceTransaction

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, evm, javascript

Has anyone else used the JavaScript-based tracer that Geth provides, as part of its [debug_traceTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction) method?

I want to look at segments of memory during a transaction's execution (specifically, I want to retrieve "input" data made by internal CALLs).

Using the JS tracer, one can access memory using `log.memory`, which has a method called `log.memory.slice`. The documentation says it,

> "returns the specified segment of memory as a byte slice".

But I can't figure out what format this *byte slice* is in.

For example, when I request a segment 4 bytes long, I get this back: `"FscnIQ=="`. How do I interpret that?

When I run `debug_traceTransaction` without the JS tracer, and print out the memory, I see that those 4 bytes should be `"0x16c72721"`.

Similarly, when I ask for the first byte in memory when memory is all 0s, the JS tracer's `log.memory.slice` returns the string `"AA=="`.
The encoding is clearly not hex, and it doesn't seem to be ASCII either.

What kind of encoding maps `"0x00"` to `"AA=="`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, okay I figured it out. The output of `log.memory.slice`is [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded.